# How get ints in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to make a blog and I want to make id tags that correspond with each time a for loop runs (e.g. #section_1, #section_2,#section_(insert variable) ).

Is there some way to do that in Jekyll?

Comment: This is really vague. Can you explain a little more. What is the input ? What is the desired output ?

Comment: I am trying make something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix2&stacked=h

with each section being a blog post

Answer (score 0):

This should produce what you're looking for:

```
{% assign indices = "1|2|3" | split: "|" %}
{% for index in indices %}
    <div id="{{ index }}">This is div {{ index }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

You'll have to know in advance how many sections that you want created, and add each ID to the `1|2|3` bit in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [forloop.index](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops)

The menu part :

```
<ul>
{% for posts in site.posts %}
  <li><a href="#section_{{ forloop.index }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Content part :

```
{% for posts in site.posts %}
  <h2 id="section_{{ forloop.index }}">{{ post.title }}</h2>
  {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```